# env_parallel:92: argument list too long: /usr/bin/parallel

Tags: zsh, gnu-parallel

I'm trying to use the solution posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50497981/9355411

and have a `.zshrc` like:

```sh
. $(which env_parallel.zsh)
```

when I make any call to `env_parallel`, I get the following error:

> `env_parallel:92: argument list too long: /usr/bin/parallel`

Comment: The error is in line 92.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I take it that you run a version < 20180722
and you run it as:

```
env_parallel echo ::: foo
```

This will try to copy your full environment (all aliases, all functions, all arrays, and all variables). Unfortunately `zsh` uses `execve` to start programs, and `execve` typically only supports 128 KB of environment.

So what to do? If you upgrade to 20190622 `env_parallel` will give this error:

```
env_parallel: Error: Your environment is too big.
env_parallel: Error: You can try 3 different approaches:
env_parallel: Error: 1. Run 'env_parallel --session' before you set
env_parallel: Error:    variables or define functions.
env_parallel: Error: 2. Use --env and only mention the names to copy.
env_parallel: Error: 3. Try running this in a clean environment once:
env_parallel: Error:      env_parallel --record-env
env_parallel: Error:    And then use '--env _'
env_parallel: Error: For details see: man env_parallel
```

So try one of those suggestions.

`--session` is supported since 20180522.